React App with Vite and TypeScript: Issues with @/components Folder Created in Root Directory After Installing Shadcn UI
I'm setting up a React app with Vite and TypeScript, and after installing Shadcn UI using npx shadcn-ui@latest init, I noticed that the components folder was created in the root directory instead of inside src. This setup also configures the @/components alias.
Given that the components folder is outside of src, how should I adjust my Vite configuration to resolve the @/components alias properly? Additionally, what changes should I make to ensure my imports work correctly with this setup?
Vite Configuration (vite.config.ts):
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@/components': path.resolve(__dirname, './components'),
      '@/lib/utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/utils'),
    },
  },
});

Shadcn UI Configuration:
`{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": false,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "src/index.css",
    "baseColor": "gray",
    "cssVariables": true,
    "prefix": ""
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
`}


Did you follow the setup instructions for vite? That should get you set up correctly

To resolve the issue, I took the following steps:

Deleted the 'components' Folder: I removed the 'components' folder from the root directory.
Updated 'components.json': I modified the 'components.json' file to change the path for components.

Here is the updated 'components.json':
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": false,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "src/index.css",
    "baseColor": "gray",
    "cssVariables": true,
    "prefix": ""
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "src/components",
    "utils": "src/lib/utils"
  }
}


Reinitialize Shadcn UI: I ran the following command to reinitialize Shadcn UI:
npx shadcn-ui@latest init

Manually Updated Imports: I updated the import statements in my components to use the correct path. Specifically, I changed:
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";


After performing these steps, I was able to resolve the issue. While this approach worked for me, I'm unsure if it is the recommended or most effective solution. Any further insights or suggestions would be appreciated.
